# Get the remote address on a GSocket

Tags: glib, gio

I have a GSocket which is accepted with g_socket_listener_accept_socket(). I want to get the remote address of the connected client, and thought the following code would do it:

```
GSocket *socket;
GSocketAddress *socket_address;
GInetAddress *inet_address;
gchar *ip_addr;

[...]

socket_address = g_socket_get_remote_address(socket_client, &err);
inet_address = g_object_ref(g_inet_socket_address_get_address(G_INET_SOCKET_ADDRESS(socket_address)));
ip_addr = g_inet_address_to_string(inet_address);

g_log(G_LOG_DOMAIN, G_LOG_LEVEL_INFO, "Login from %s", ip_addr);

g_free(ip_addr);
g_object_unref(socket_address);
```

However, I get the following error:

```
(process:15761): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: g_inet_address_to_string: assertion `G_IS_INET_ADDRESS (address)' failed
```

After some debugging, it turned out that the above message is generated by g_inet_address_to_string().

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: add some asserts: `g_assert (inet_address); g_assert (G_IS_INET_ADDRESS (inet_address))` (do not munch them into one assert)

Comment: inet_address is not NULL, G_IS_INET_ADDRESS returns FALSE, however

Comment: Can you create a minimal compilable example, I will have a deeper look into it.